Can't set x5t in header of JWT
I'm using the jwx library by lestrrat following library.
According to the docs, the following code should work:
headers := jws.NewHeaders()
err = headers.Set("x5t", getThumbprint(cert))
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

// sign the jwt
signedToken, err := jwt.Sign(token, jwt.WithKey(jwa.RS256, privateKey), jwt.WithHeaders(headers))
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

However, the code doesn't compile and in GoLand, I'm told:

Unresolved reference 'WithHeaders'

What am I missing?
